# Web Service require SSL only for some urls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf-rest

Is it possible to have a web service require ssl on some urls but not on others? The service as a whole provides 1 function but talks to 2 different clients. I can split it into 2 different services if necessary but was wondering if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS (i'm using version 7), there is a option for you site called SSL Settings, in there make sure the Require SSL checkbox is unchecked.  This will not force SSL on the service.

However, this will not prevent your SSL required client from using the non SSL link, it will basically allow you to hit the service with and without SSL.

Comment: Yeah, the site as a whole doesn't require SSL, just this service for that client. I'm looking for a service-level configuration, if it exists.

Comment: if you are using wcf, maybe try two endpoints, one with SSL and one without.

Comment: Good idea, that might do what I want.